# In a Typical nw application why do we need NotifyRouteChange

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, windows-7, windows-networking

I have an application which registers for NotifyRouteChange() and wait in a async call. We know that based on the routing table change by Windows OS this API is called back. I would need more info on what makes Windows to trigger this function?

In one of my environment Win 7 Professional, I'm getting 100 IP address change notification within one sec. how to reduce it?

Thanks,
Saravana

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you would genuinely receive that many notifications. Can you post some code that shows how you are handling the notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an environment issue.

I have used

```
   ret = NotifyAddrChange(handle, &overlap);
   ret = NotifyRouteChange(handle, &overlap));
```

Then there is a call back function to monitor for these registrations, if there is any change in IP address / Route these callback have been initiated. 
And these call back func have passed these notification to my other threads to handle, and register again for the same API.

This problem has not occurred in all machines, but in particular environment. i have network which doesn't throws any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a waitable timer to dampen the events so your event handler(s) fire after a minimum time after the last NW change event:

Basically when you receive a address/route change event:

1. Set a waitable timer (for 5 secs) (SetWaitableTimer)
2. Every time the address/route event becomes signalled, cancel the existing waitable timer (CancelWaitableTimer) and goto 1.
3. If the waitable time becomes signalled, then it means that the address/route change events have not occurred in the last 5 secs. call your NW change handler(s) here.